# Invalid combination of opcodes and operands when adding two registers

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I'm writing a piece of assembly code designed to get keyboard input using a BIOS interrupt, then print it to the screen with another BIOS interrupt. I am using the NASM compiler for x86 systems.  At line 19 of my code (marked with an asterisk (*), I am getting the "invalid combination of opcodes and operands" error.  I know this generally represents any number of syntactical errors, but at my skill level, I can't work down to any specifics, sorry.  Here's my code chunk:

```
; ---------------------------------------------
; Get input (hangs on input and loops forever)
; ---------------------------------------------
GetInput:
```

XOR AH, AH                 ;AH = 0 for interrupt 16.0
INT 0x16                   ;Fetch the next key pressed.
MOV SI, keymap             ;Set SI to the head pointer of the keymap
ADD SI, AH                 ;Increase the pointer by the key number.
*MOV AL, [SI]              ;Load the returned key for printing.
CALL PrintCharacter        ;Print the key
CALL GetInput              ;Wait on the next key.
RET

Let me know if you need any more information, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that that your mistake is one line before.
You can't mix 16 bit and 8 bit registers in x86 like:

```
ADD SI, AH
```

If you want to add AH register to SI than copy (zero extend) AH to AX first, like:

```
MOVZX AX, AH
ADD   SI, AX
```

Comment: This definitely seems to be the problem.  I replaced EAX with AX in your code, as I'm only using 16 bit assembly.  MOVZX should work properly in either case though, right?

Comment: Sorry, I was too fast and didn't test the code. AX instead EAX is correct! Yes MOVZX works properly in both cases.